# Obstacle avoiding by Pi camera

Tags: mobile-robot, raspberry-pi, mapping, python, opencv

I designed a mobile robot with my colleagues for our graduation project, the purpose of it is to detect mines (metals) in a specific area

We are programming the robot using Python on Raspberry Pi 3

I want it to avoid obstacles using the Pi camera, is that possible through computer vision?

I searched a lot but I can't find a full reference that guides me to do it.

If it is too hard we'll use an ultrasonic sensor but can it, at least, make a graphical updated map, that marks the position of mines and obstacles on it?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mahmoud, but I'm afraid that questions like this are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: thanks mark for your replay
I modified it. I hope it is fine now

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mahmoud, but your question is still too broad to be practically answerable. As it says in the [faq#dontask]: "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."